# ROBLOX - Fixing the gaps in hexagon terrain

Tags: lua, heightmap, roblox

So, I've been messing around with some heightmap code from [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Random_terrain#Height-map)

After messing around with the parameters, I changed the part of a hexagon shape and made a nice diamond like formation with it, but the problem is, there's gaps where the hexagon sides don't meet up shown [here](https://twitter.com/Tha_pumpking/status/659776557611950080)

here's the code responsible for generating and such:

```
local size = Vector3.new(10, -- Number of tiles along the width
                         10, -- Number of steps of heightmap
                         10) -- Number of tiles along the length

local base  = script.Parent -- The part to replace with terrain

math.randomseed(tick()%1e5)

for x = 1, size.x do
    for z = 1, size.z do
        local y =x+z
        wait()
        local tile = game.ServerStorage.Hexagon:Clone()

        local position = Vector3.new(x-1, 0, z-1) * tile.Size
        tile.Size = tile.Size * Vector3.new(1, y, 1)
        tile.CFrame = CFrame.new(tile.Size/2)     --Shift the part by half it's size, so we can position the corner
        tile.CFrame = tile.CFrame - base.Size / 2 --Shift it into one corner of the base
        tile.CFrame = tile.CFrame + position      --Put it in the right place
        tile.CFrame = base.CFrame * tile.CFrame   --Move it so that it is level with the surface of the base
        tile.Parent=workspace

        if tile.Position.Y < 30 then
            tile.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Brown")
        elseif tile.Position.Y > 30 and tile.Position.Y < 100 then
            tile.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright green")
        end
    end
end -- an end for each for loop

base:Destroy()
```

Comment: `local position = (Vector3.new(.75, 0, -.5) * (x-1) + Vector3.new(.75, 0, .5) * (z-1)) * tile.Size`

Comment: You're beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Updated to get rid of diamond-shaped group (see the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the solution to this problem is how you set the position. Try this instead:

```
local position = (Vector3.new(.75, 0, -.5)*(x-1) + Vector3.new(.75, 0, .5)*(z-1))*tile.Size
```

---

EDIT:

Full code (it also forms the group of tiles as "big hexagon" instead of "big diamond"):

```
local size = 10 -- Number of tiles along the side of "big hexagon"

local base  = script.Parent -- The part to replace with terrain

math.randomseed(tick()%1e5)

for x = 0, 2*size do
    for z = 0, 2*size do
        if ((x + z)/size - 2)^2 > 1 then break end
        local y = x+z
        wait()
        local tile = game.ServerStorage.Hexagon:Clone()

        local position = Vector3.new(.75*(x+z), 0, .5*(z-x)) * tile.Size
        tile.Size = tile.Size * Vector3.new(1, y, 1)
        tile.CFrame = CFrame.new(tile.Size/2)     --Shift the part by half it's size, so we can position the corner
        tile.CFrame = tile.CFrame - base.Size / 2 --Shift it into one corner of the base
        tile.CFrame = tile.CFrame + position      --Put it in the right place
        tile.CFrame = base.CFrame * tile.CFrame   --Move it so that it is level with the surface of the base
        tile.Parent=workspace

        if tile.Position.Y < 30 then
            tile.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Brown")
        elseif tile.Position.Y > 30 and tile.Position.Y < 100 then
            tile.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright green")
        end
    end
end -- an end for each for loop

base:Destroy()
```